# Browser Resolving Host, Program Delays

Tags: windows-7, networking, connection

For some reason when I'm idle on my computer or when I boot up, I can open my browser it will stay on `Resolving host...` for 5 minutes or so even though the network is connected. This causes programs to delay opening. Then as soon as the host issue fixes on my browser, all of my programs which I tried to open before start up.

Is there a reason why its doing this? I have an SSD drive, boots up really fast. I'm using Avast AV and MBAM. No services running which require ports. Could this be a setting on my router or at my ISPs end? All other devices and computers on my network don't have this issue.. I'm using Google DNS also.